# How to Integrate D-Pad Focus Navigation?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm currently trying to make a Netflix-style UI in Flutter on my Android TV. I've been struggling with integrating focus navigation for the past few days and figured I'd ask here as there doesn't really seem to be any in-depth tutorials.

Right now I'd like to be able to navigate my ListView Builder using d-pad controls and add a special state to the widget to signify that it's currently selected (enlarged or with a border).

Here's my current code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeState createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
      child: FutureBuilder(
          // an asset :bundle is just the resources used by a given application
          future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
              .loadString('assets/json/featured.json'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            // Loading indicator
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text(snapshot.error); // or whatever
            }

            var mediaData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
            List<Session> mediaDataSession =
                (mediaData as List<dynamic>).cast<Session>();

            // Pass our array data into the Session class' fromJson method and allow it to be iterable
            var decodedData =
                mediaData.map((data) => Session.fromJson(data)).toList();

            BoxDecoration myBoxDecoration() {
              return BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
              );
            }

            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Text('Featured',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: 'HelveticaNeue',
                            fontSize: 24.0)),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  // Focus was here before
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: mediaData.length,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: Container(
                              margin:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, top: 4.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                    .start, // Workaround for aligning text
                                children: [
                                      Container(
                                        // Find a way to render based on focus being true
                                        decoration: myBoxDecoration(),
                                        child: InkWell(
//                                          onTap: () => {},
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                                          focusColor: Colors.black,
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            height: 150.0,
                                            child: ClipRRect(
                                                child: Image.network(
                                                    mediaData[index]['image'])),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                                    child: Text(mediaData[index]['name'],
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 17.0,
                                            fontFamily: "HelveticaNeue",
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

For reference, I'd like to get behaviour like this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l37VYXhRhPQ

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code of the app in the video:
https://gitlab.com/ad-on-is/chillyflix/

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I also found this great article: https://www.programmersought.com/article/1289789613/

Comment: hey @aknd the  URL is not active , can you please share the active link ?

Comment: gitlab link requires sign in; github link is dead. It _might_ be this one: https://github.com/EngineerDanny/chillyflix